# Max velocity of turtlebot

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I have been simulating a turtlebot3 waffle pi in Gazebo, and been using velocities as high as 0.5m/s. Looking at the hardware specifications: https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/platform/turtlebot3/features/, it says that the max velocity is 0.26 m/s. Does this mean that it can drive at 0.5m/s in the simulations, but not physically because of hardware limitations?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/393349/max-velocity-of-turtlebot/) by [Roshan](https://answers.ros.org/users/85346/roshan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2021-12-26

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-12-26**:
Hi @Roshan

If the simulation is higher than specs it must be that a configuration file has been changed. I checked from the repo and the simulation matches robot spec:

BURGER_MAX_LIN_VEL = 0.22
BURGER_MAX_ANG_VEL = 2.84

WAFFLE_MAX_LIN_VEL = 0.26
WAFFLE_MAX_ANG_VEL = 1.82

LIN_VEL_STEP_SIZE = 0.01
ANG_VEL_STEP_SIZE = 0.1

https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3/blob/master/turtlebot3_teleop/nodes/turtlebot3_teleop_key

**Comment by [Roshan](https://answers.ros.org/users/85346/roshan/) on 2021-12-26**:
That's weird, I haven't changed the configuration file, but I can still publish for example 0.5 or 1 into the cmd_vel and see changes. Does the 0.5 I'm publishing into the cmd_vel mean something other than velocity maybe?

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-12-26**:
And here as well: https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_simulations/blob/master/turtlebot3_fake/include/turtlebot3_fake/turtlebot3_fake.h

```
#define MAX_LINEAR_VELOCITY             0.22   // m/s
#define MAX_ANGULAR_VELOCITY            2.84   // rad/s
```

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-12-26**:
You can publish any speed but the robot will just go to your max speed

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-12-26**:
I think you may be right:

```
void Turtlebot3Fake::commandVelocityCallback(const geometry_msgs::TwistConstPtr cmd_vel_msg)
{
  last_cmd_vel_time_ = ros::Time::now();

  goal_linear_velocity_  = cmd_vel_msg->linear.x;
  goal_angular_velocity_ = cmd_vel_msg->angular.z;

  wheel_speed_cmd_[LEFT]  = goal_linear_velocity_ - (goal_angular_velocity_ * wheel_seperation_ / 2);
  wheel_speed_cmd_[RIGHT] = goal_linear_velocity_ + (goal_angular_velocity_ * wheel_seperation_ / 2);
}
```

https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_simulations/blob/master/turtlebot3_fake/src/turtlebot3_fake.cpp

It never checks against max velocity just checks against published velocity

**Comment by [Roshan](https://answers.ros.org/users/85346/roshan/) on 2021-12-26**:
Ah ok, so that does mean that the simulations don't actually have a max velocity, but once you start using a physical setup the max velocity will be at 0.26 m/s for linear velocity

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-12-26**:
That’s correct. You could add the checks like in the teleop program

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-12-27**:
Hi @Roshan, Added an answer to complete the cycle and summarize our discussion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As keenly observed by @Roshan, the Turtlebot3 simulation linear velocity can be set higher than the physical robot.

The main function:

```
void Turtlebot3Fake::commandVelocityCallback(const geometry_msgs::TwistConstPtr cmd_vel_msg)
{
  last_cmd_vel_time_ = ros::Time::now();

  goal_linear_velocity_  = cmd_vel_msg->linear.x;
  goal_angular_velocity_ = cmd_vel_msg->angular.z;

  wheel_speed_cmd_[LEFT]  = goal_linear_velocity_ - (goal_angular_velocity_ * wheel_seperation_ / 2);
  wheel_speed_cmd_[RIGHT] = goal_linear_velocity_ + (goal_angular_velocity_ * wheel_seperation_ / 2);
}
```

https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_simulations/blob/master/turtlebot3_fake/src/turtlebot3_fake.cpp

Doesn't check for:

```
#define MAX_LINEAR_VELOCITY             0.22   // m/s
#define MAX_ANGULAR_VELOCITY            2.84   // rad/s
```

found at: https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_simulations/blob/master/turtlebot3_fake/include/turtlebot3_fake/turtlebot3_fake.h

To simulate accurately, it's suggested to just a check for maximum velocity like in the `teleop program`:

```
def checkLinearLimitVelocity(vel):
    if turtlebot3_model == "burger":
      vel = constrain(vel, -BURGER_MAX_LIN_VEL, BURGER_MAX_LIN_VEL)
    elif turtlebot3_model == "waffle" or turtlebot3_model == "waffle_pi":
      vel = constrain(vel, -WAFFLE_MAX_LIN_VEL, WAFFLE_MAX_LIN_VEL)
    else:
      vel = constrain(vel, -BURGER_MAX_LIN_VEL, BURGER_MAX_LIN_VEL)

    return vel
```

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2021-12-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1